# a java static method

Tags: java, static

I have a class like this

```
public class StockCodes
{

    public static boolean loaded = false;
    public static long lastUpdate = 0;
    private static long freq = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    public static HashMap<String, Stock> stockMap = new HashMap<String, Stock>();

    public static ArrayList<Stock> getCodes()
    {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((StockCodes.loaded) && ((now - StockCodes.lastUpdate) < freq))
        {
            System.out.println(StockCodes.loaded);
            return stockList;

        } 
    else
        {
            HttpFetcher fetcher = new HttpFetcher();

        ....

            log.info("Load " + stockList.size() + " Stocks");
            StockCodes.loaded = true;
            StockCodes.lastUpdate = now;
            return stockList;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StockCodes.getCodes();
    }
}
```

When I run the java application , it outputs "true". Telling us the stockcodes have loaded.
But when i debug the java appliction, it goes into the else. I do not understand why it runs in this way, especially why it outputs "true" the first time i run the application. Could someone else give me some help ,thank you ~

Comment: What's in the "`....`"? Possibly a `StockCodes.getCodes()` call?

Comment: In both instances - what are you doing?  From what you've shown us, this program should never output true, but it looks like you're debugging by running through the main method and when you 'run the java application' something else setting StockCodes = true before exiting.

Comment: I dont see any advantage of using boolean variable. Instead you can use an init method(reson is once you set the boolean variable into true state it remains true forever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code given above, the control by default should always go in the `else` block and print nothing. You can verify it.

Not if you have some more places where you call the `getCodes()` method, then it will differ. Having said this, please verify if there is no other place with a call to `getCodes()`. ie its invoked single time via `main()`

Answer (score 0):

The getCodes() function essentially caches the result if the function has been run more than once.  The first getCodes() will not print "true", but all subsequent calls will

Run from the command line

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    StockCodes.getCodes();
}
```

this should output nothing to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement is clean. When I have one of these type of mistakes I go the old fashion route. I put a series of

```
System.out.println
```

statements in that section of the code to track where you code is going when it not in debug mode. It is clunky but it works.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code it goes through the `else` whether I run in debug mode or regular.

I think you lost a line of your code.  Did you have 
            System.out.println(StockCodes.loaded);
in your `else` branch also?  If you did, and you had it located below your line `StockCodes.loaded = true;` then it will be printing `true` for you.

I suggest you use more detailed debugging, something like `System.out.println("In the if branch");` and below that in the else branch, a line like `System.out.println("In the else branch");`  I think you are tricking yourself by having too little output.